# How can I display all of these fields?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can already retrieve the document and it shows in the console but how can I retrieve the individual fields so I can display it in the screen?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("orders")
      .where("uid", "==", user.id)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.data() })));
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

i wanted to get these individual fields and how can I map through the "items"array?

[image]

This is what it shows in the console.log and I wanted to access and display the individual fields like the address, items, and delivery date

[image]

Document Data as JSON:
[{"id":{"displayName":"Jenn ","items":[{"productPrice":"130","productUserHandler":null,"createdDate":{"seconds":1617787002,"nanoseconds":70000000},"qty":1,"productDesc":"Cheese ","productName":"Pizza","productImg":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ajc-pizza.appspot.com/o/product-images%2Ftunapizza.jpg?alt=media&token=e307d9aa-bc67-4262-94e7-7c7346cc933b","documentID":"MS1PmRyGTWitCaLtV5Xk"},{"documentID":"ndxxdJyS40aRcndJLg9E","productUserHandler":null,"qty":1,"productPrice":"130","productName":"Pizza","productImg":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ajc-pizza.appspot.com/o/product-images%2Fvegetablepizza.jpg?alt=media&token=6f02cd14-6bd9-40dd-9b31-95925578422b","createdDate":{"seconds":1617787021,"nanoseconds":448000000},"productDesc":"Vegetables / Cheese"}],"deliveryDate":"2021-05-08","orderCreatedAt":{"seconds":1619862395,"nanoseconds":463000000},"userID":"kGhSlhM2pIgL9srfXviw9Xew4mI3","total":260,"phone":"+63 9353 276961","address":"US"}},{"id":{"phone":"(555) 555-1234","items":[{"productImg":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ajc-pizza.appspot.com/o/product-images%2Ftunapizza.jpg?alt=media&token=e307d9aa-bc67-4262-94e7-7c7346cc933b","qty":2,"createdDate":{"seconds":1617787002,"nanoseconds":70000000},"documentID":"MS1PmRyGTWitCaLtV5Xk","productName":"Tuna Pizza","productPrice":"130","productUserHandler":null,"productDesc":"Tuna / Cheese "}],"deliveryDate":"2021-05-03","address":"US","displayName":"Jenn ","total":260,"userID":"kGhSlhM2pIgL9srfXviw9Xew4mI3","orderCreatedAt":{"seconds":1619857372,"nanoseconds":32000000}}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no field named as `uid` in the document. So please make sure you add it first else the 'where' query won't work as intended. You cannot fetch a single field from Firestore. First fetch the whole document and then use the relevant data.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("orders")
      .where("uid", "==", user.id)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          const userOrders = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ [doc.id]: doc.data() }));
          console.log(userOrders);
          // Logging items of first order
          // console.log(userOrders[0]["items"])
        
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Please use `[doc.id]: doc.data()` in the map so the keys will be the order IDs (document IDs). When it comes to rendering those on your webpage, you need to use a map function to render all orders first and another map function inside of each to render the items. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The picture wasn't complete but there's uid I stored in the document which it does show correctly in the console. The "console.log(userOrders[0]["items"])" shows exactly the same as the userOrders.

Comment: @JenJennie can you please share your document data as JSON so I can test that on my side ?

Comment: @JenJennie I meant `console.log(JSON.stringify(userOrders))` and share ?

Comment: @JenJennie I doubt if you have made this change `https://imgur.com/W9eyJM6`. Please make that because all the order IDs in your JSON are just a string "id".

Comment: Oh wait, console.log(userOrders[0]["items"]) this one worked, btw, I used,  console.log(userOrders[0].id.address) and I could already show it in the console the same with the items too. I did it using "console.log(userOrders[0].id.items[0].productPrice);" but is there some way I could dynamically map throught the items array?

Comment: will check that too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231839/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-jen-jennie).

Comment: I still have another issue with the displaying it on the screen. I can't seem to use the orders.map. This is my newest code:                                                          
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("orders")
      .where("userID", "==", currentUser.id)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
          arr.push({
            [doc.id]: doc.data(),
          })
        );
        setOrders(arr);
        console.log(arr);
      });
    };
  }, []);

Comment: @JenJennie please let's chat in the discussion,  can you please share your react file in the discussion chat